# pgfplot undefined control sequence - (when using utf-8 files with BOM)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm getting undefined control sequence here: but the code and the csv files look alright.  (This worked at some point).  Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usetikzlibrary{fillbetween,shapes,positioning,arrows,calc}
\begin{document}





% Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.12}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width = \linewidth,
date coordinates in=x,
date ZERO=2014-12-11,
stack plots=y,
area style,
enlarge x limits=false,
xticklabel style={
    rotate=90,
    anchor=near xticklabel,
},
% set the label style of the `xtick's
xticklabel=\month - \year,
]
\addplot table [x=isodate, y=width, col sep=comma] {measures.csv} \closedcycle;
\addplot table [x=isodate, y=height, col sep=comma] {measures.csv} \closedcycle;;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Erro details:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError ...
#4 \errhelp \@err@ ...
l.2408 ...] {measures.csv} \closedcycle;
^^M
```

Sample file:measures.csv

```
date,isodate,temperature,width,height
11-Dec-14,2014-12-11,1,0,1
12-Jan-15,2015-01-22,3,0,2
```

Comment: Works fine here, can you turn your snippet into a complete, minimal document that reproduces the error? That is, a complete file from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` so that it can be compiled without modifications.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  I added the headers the issue seems to be \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} .   However when I check my file with file -i measures.csv I get text/plain; charset=utf-8.

Comment: You forgot `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Again though, it works fine here when I add that and use a `measures.csv` I made myself. Can you show a sample of the CSV file (or the whole thing, if it's small)? Edit: Also, make sure that the reduced example you show actually reproduce the error. I.e. test it before you post.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Updated as I've tested it. Still undefined control sequence

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't be of help, as I can't reproduce the error, and I don't know in what circumstances an error like that will occur, so I can't even guess.

Comment: I don't get any error here too. But I also get `charset=us-ascii` with `file -i measures.csv` for the file copied from here. I guess, that there is something wrong with your .csv file, maybe some character code invisible here. Check your .csv file with a hex editor, or copy it from here and try again.

Comment: The issue is also reported here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373316/pgfplotstablesave-results-in-error-when-utf8x-is-used-version-1-14-texlive-201  is related to texlive 2017.  I have utf-8 files.

Comment: @Mike @ TorbjørnT  Thanks folks turns out the problem is the BOM mark at the beginning of the files, however, this worked at some point for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgfplot does not support well UTF-8 files with BOM encodings.  Typically identifiable by the EF BB BF bytes at the beginning of the file.

Many thanks to @Mike and and @TorbjørnT for helping out in identifying the problem.